# Go to particular carousel slide in angular js

Tags: angularjs, carousel

I am doing basic angular carousel slider. Here we want a separate section, which will slide the slider to particular one. How do we achieve this. I have shown a sample in image. If I click on 1 it should go to 1st slide and so. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Check [angular-carousel](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel), see an example [here](http://blog.revolunet.com/angular-carousel/)